# How to keep VARCHAR in the DB (MYSQL), but ENUM in the sqlalchemy model

Tags: python, mysql, enums, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to add a new Int column to my MYSQL DB, so that in the sqlalchemy ORM it will be converted to an ENUM.

For example, let's say I have this enum:

```
class employee_type(Enum):
    Full_time = 1
    Part_time = 2
    Student = 3
```

I want to keep in the DB those params - `1,2,3...`, but when developers will write code that involves this model - they will just use the `Enum`, without having to go through getter and setter functions.

So they will be able to do - `instance_of_model.employee_type` and get an `Enum`. And - `new_instance = model_name(employee_type=Employee_type.Full_time..)`

How should I define my sqlalchemy model so it will work? (I've heard of hybrid types but not sure it will work here)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is super simple(!), there is nothing special we need to do - SQLAlchemy support it by itself.

Meaning - you can set the specific column to be `INT` in the DB, but `enum` in the model, and when querying the DB SQLAlchemy will convert it by itself. same goes when inserting to the DB :)

I used it with declarative enum, it means it's values are strings (and it has a function - `from_string()`).
So once I used `VARCHAR` columns, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Sqlalchemy checks the db if native type enum is available.

If the db does not support this, the default type is VARCHAR.

So you can

```
Enum(MyEnum, native_enum=False)
```